# Why I got NonExistentClass in Kotlin when using AutoFactory?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, autofactory

I use AutoFactory in Kotlin  and I receive the issue , I haven't had any issue when I was using java . What is the problem that I receive this issue?

`TopicLoaderModule_Companion_ProvidePageLoaderViewFactory.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  private final Provider<NonExistentClass> pageElementFactoryProvider;`

```
    @Provided private val presenter: Presenter,
       private val model: Model
)


@Module
interface TopicLoaderModule{
companion object {

@JvmStatic
@Provides
fun provideXXX(pageElementFactory: TopicElementFactory){
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to post an answer to my question.

```
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#non-existent-type-correction